# ContourPlot combined with Piecewise bug

Tags: plotting, piecewise

I'm plotting a two dimensional von Mises and Tresca yield surface and got:

```
ContourPlot[{Sqrt[sr^2 - sr st + st^2] == 1, Abs[(sr - st)/2] == 1/2, 
  sr == 1, st == 1, sr == -1, st == -1}, {sr, -2, 2}, {st, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

I need to cut the lines that are crossing the smooth surface. So I tried:

```
piece = Piecewise[{{st == 1, 0 <= sr <= 1}, {sr == 1, 
    0 <= st <= 1}, {st == 1, -1 <= sr <= 0}, {sr == 1, -1 <= st <= 0}}]
ContourPlot[{Sqrt[sr^2 - sr st + st^2] == 1, Abs[(sr - st)/2] == 1/2, 
  piece}, {sr, -2, 2}, {st, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

What's the issue here?

Comment: Perhaps its that the theory underlying `ContourPlot` assumes the function is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this is what you are after?

```
ContourPlot[{
  Max[Abs[x - y], Abs[x], Abs[y]] == 1,
  Sqrt[x^2 - x y + y^2] == 1
  }, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
    PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The problem arises because Piecewise is evaluated sequentually. FullSimplify shows, you get False.

```
FullSimplify[piece]
```

[image]

You better work with Exclusions in ContourPlot

```
ContourPlot[{Sqrt[sr^2 - sr st + st^2] == 1, Abs[(sr - st)/2] == 1/2, 
   sr == 1, st == 1, sr == -1, st == -1}, {sr, -2, 2}, {st, -2, 2}, 
    Exclusions -> {{sr == 1, Sqrt[sr^2 - sr st + st^2] <= 1}, {sr == -1, 
    Sqrt[sr^2 - sr st + st^2] <= 1}, {st == 1, 
    Sqrt[sr^2 - sr st + st^2] <= 1}, {st == -1, 
    Sqrt[sr^2 - sr st + st^2] <= 1}}]
```

[image]

You can play with PlotPoints and MaxRecursion to fill the gaps.